# Finding Office RT program version

Tags: windows-rt, microsoft-office-2013

How can I see exact version number from inside Microsoft's Word RT, Powerpoint RT, Access RT, and Excel RT (not checking the actual `.exe` file)?

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on "HELP" on the file menu and then selecting "ABOUT..." shows the version information. Or at least in outlook 2007 it does.

In Word 2007 I have to click on the "office" button, go to word options and then select resources from the list. There is an option to see the system/version information there, I don't know if that's the same for 2013.

Edit: Actually, found [this link](http://blogmines.com/blog/2012/07/21/how-to-check-version-of-office-2013-products/) that shows you how to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to go to File->Help. This should display the version

Comment: There is no File / Help option as you can see above.

Answer (score 0):

`File / Account / About Word` (similarly for other Office RT apps):

[image: 1]